# What values should I take of input_shape of LSTM in below model

Tags: python, keras, lstm

[These is the image of the code LSTM model please help me to give appropriate input_dim value for the first LSTM layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG6gB.png)

Comment: Please do not include code as images, and additonally, provide information about the shape of your data (actual shape values, not just it being 3D).

Answer (score 0):

For the code you gave, all possible answers are wrong.

A LSTM layer accepts a 3D input tensor of shape `(batch_dim, time_dim, feat_dim)`, and you should write `input_shape=(time_dim, feat_dim)` in the layer definition.

However, since you use`X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=0)`, it implies there is only one training sample in your data, which completely makes no sense. I therefore suspect what you really want to do is

`X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=-1)`

which has `X_train.shape[0]` of samples, `X_train.shape[1]` of time steps, and only 1 feature dimension, which is sort of common in many time-series analysis problem.

If my guess is correct, then your input shape of LSTM should be of shape `(X_train.shape[1], 1)`.

NOTE: the `batch_dim` is intentionally not specified by keras's setting, which  makes sense, because if you include it in your model definition, then you have to use to this particular batch size for both training and testing, while this is very inconvenient.